# How to make UITextfield accept english litters and numbers only ? swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How to make UITextfield accept english litters and numbers only ? I found solutions but all in objective-c

how to do it in swift ?

Comment: Select the text field and in attribute inspector change the keyboard type to Name and phone pad. Now you can enter only alphabets and numbers.

Comment: @shaileshChandavar still I can type another languages !!!

Comment: @NazmulHasan You don't need permission to post an answer. If you have one, post it.

Comment: @Zizoo There are many Swift examples showing how to filter what can be typed into a text field. What exactly have you tried so far? What issue do you have? Update your question with relevant code.